# Re-doing a reverted merge in Git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have run into a bit of a problem here: I had a problem-specific branch `28s` in Git, that I merged in the general `develop` branch. Turns out I had done it too fast, so I used git-revert to undo the merge. Now, however, the time has come to merge `28s` into `develop`, but git-merge command sees the original merge, and happily announces that all is well and branches have been already merged. What do I do now? Create a 'Revert "Revert "28s -> develop"" ' commit? Doesn't seem to be a good way to do it, but I can't imagine any other at the moment.

What the tree structure looks like:

[image: Git log output]

Comment: It's GitX (http://gitx.frim.nl).

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You have to "revert the revert". Depending on you how did the original revert, it may not be as easy as it sounds. Look at the [official document on this topic](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W---x---Y
              /
      ---A---B-------------------C---D
```

to allow:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x-------x-------*
              /                       /
      ---A---B-------------------C---D
```

> But does it all work? Sure it does. You can revert a merge, and from a
>   purely technical angle, git did it very naturally and had no real
>   troubles.
>   It just considered it a change from "state before merge" to
>   "state after merge", and that was it.
>   Nothing complicated, nothing odd,
>   nothing really dangerous. Git will do it without even thinking about it.
>
> So from a technical angle, there's nothing wrong with reverting a merge,
>   but **from a workflow angle it's something that you generally should try to
>   avoid**.
>
> If at all possible, for example, if you find a problem that got merged
>   into the main tree, **rather than revert the merge, try *really* hard to**:
>
> - bisect the problem down into the branch you merged, and just fix it,
> - or try to revert the individual commit that caused it.
>
> Yes, it's more complex, and no, it's not always going to work (sometimes
>   the answer is: "oops, I really shouldn't have merged it, because it wasn't
>   ready yet, and I really need to undo *all* of the merge"). So then you
>   really should revert the merge, but when you want to re-do the merge, you
>   now need to do it by reverting the revert.

Comment: Good link (+1). I took the liberty to copy part of the document in your answer in order to allow readers to see immediately the relevant options in this case. If you disagree, feel free to revert.

Comment: We just ran into a case where we needed to do this and found that the fun doesn't quite stop here. It was a long running branch that was merged in, so we needed to continue to update it. My approach here: http://tech.patientslikeme.com/2010/09/29/dealing-with-git-merge-revisions/

Comment: i followed @jdwyah's blog post and it was glorious (seriously, it was awesome that it just worked).

Comment: @jdwyah that seems to be a broken link, but it sounds like an interesting read. Here is a archive.org mirror but it is missing the images: https://web.archive.org/web/20111229193713/http://tech.patientslikeme.com/2010/09/29/dealing-with-git-merge-revisions

Comment: Another link that also suggests "reverting the revert": [link](http://metlos.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/git-merging-after-a-revert/).

Comment: Blog post has been resurrected, thanks: http://blog.jdwyah.com/2015/07/dealing-with-git-merge-revisions.html

Comment: I followed @jdwyah post too. It worked great, I would only change the 'git revert SHA_OF_THE_MERGE_REVERSION' for 'SHA_OF_THE_REVERT_MERGE' or something similar.

Comment: "revert the revert" :D. Can't imagine that I'm doing that :D

Comment: Current link to @jdwyah's post https://blog.jdwyah.com/2015/07/07/dealing-with-git-merge-revisions.html

Comment: In bitbucket I reverted that revert branch it will ask you for create new branch of reverted branch , so you can merge that branch in master again in future. it will show track also

Answer (score 83):

Let's assume you have such history

```
---o---o---o---M---W---x-------x-------*
              /                      
      ---A---B
```

Where  A, B failed commits and W - is revert of M

So before I start fixing found problems I do cherry-pick of W commit to my branch

```
git cherry-pick -x W
```

Then I revert W commit on my branch

```
git revert W
```

After I can continue fixing.

The final history could look like:

```
---o---o---o---M---W---x-------x-------*
              /                       /     
      ---A---B---W---W`----------C---D
```

When I send a PR it will clearly shows that PR is undo revert and adds some new commits.

Comment: This looks like it could be helpful, but is so sparse on the details (what are C, D in the last diagram) that it's more frustrating than useful

Comment: @Isochronous C and D seem to be commits that fix the problems introduced by A and B.

Comment: @Thomas exactly

Comment: It's good that you have highlighted using a PR in this instance as it can provide a final 'sanity check' before merging back to master.

Comment: use why do you restart your branch from the original W? I.e., let your topic continue from W, with W` followed by C and D? That removes some duplication

Answer (score 57):

To revert the revert without screwing up your workflow too much:

- Create a local trash copy of develop
- Revert the revert commit on the local copy of develop
- Merge that copy into your feature branch, and push your feature branch to your git server.

Your feature branch should now be able to be merged as normal when you're ready for it.  The only downside here is that you'll a have a few extra merge/revert commits in your history.

Comment: Just to prevent any further mix ups I also created a 'trash' copy of my feature branch and merged the reverted develop into it.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the only answer that actually explains how to do it instead of saying you shouldn't do this. Really helpfull.

Comment: thank you, my case was pretty simple so this totally got the job done for me. The other answers are awesome too if you are in a more complex situation.

Answer (score 28):

To revert a revert in GIT:

```
git revert <commit-hash-of-previous-revert>
```

Comment: Using this in my work branch to revert the revert, then new PR to develop. Now git sees all changes that were in the previous PR that was reverted. Thanks.

Comment: Lifesaving revert method! Now to revert the revert of the original revert.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `git-revert` you could have used this command in the `devel` branch to **throw away** (undo) the wrong merge commit (instead of just reverting it).

```
git checkout devel
git reset --hard COMMIT_BEFORE_WRONG_MERGE
```

This will also adjust the contents of the working directory accordingly. **Be careful**:

- **Save your changes** in the develop branch (since the wrong merge) because they
  too will be erased by the `git-reset`. All commits after the one you specify as
  the `git reset` argument will be gone!
- Also, don't do this if your changes were already pulled from other repositories
  because the reset will rewrite history.

I recommend to study the `git-reset` man-page carefully before trying this.

Now, after the reset you can re-apply your changes in `devel` and then do

```
git checkout devel
git merge 28s
```

This will be a real merge from `28s` into `devel` like the initial one (which is now
erased from git's history).

Comment: For anyone who is not super familiar with git and might want to follow these instructions: careful with combining `reset --hard` and `push origin`. Also be aware a force push to origin may really muck up open PRs on GitHub.

Comment: Very helpful for fixing some merge issues on a private git server. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for this technique. Potentially destructive, but can save you a lot of headache (and a mangled history) when applied judiciously.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to follow below steps to revert a revert, say SHA1.

```
git checkout develop #go to develop branch
git pull             #get the latest from remote/develop branch
git branch users/yourname/revertOfSHA1 #having HEAD referring to develop
git checkout users/yourname/revertOfSHA1 #checkout the newly created branch
git log --oneline --graph --decorate #find the SHA of the revert in the history, say SHA1
git revert SHA1
git push --set-upstream origin users/yourname/revertOfSHA1 #push the changes to remote
```

Now create PR for the branch `users/yourname/revertOfSHA1`

Answer (score 2):

1. create new branch at commit prior to the original merge - call it it 'develop-base'
2. perform interactive rebase of 'develop' on top of 'develop-base'  (even though it's already on top).  During interactive rebase, you'll have the opportunity to remove both the merge commit, and the commit that reversed the merge, i.e. remove  both events from git history

At this point you'll have a clean 'develop' branch to which you can merge your feature brach as you regularly do.

Comment: This approach will create problem if the develop branch is shared with others.

Comment: This can likely be improved by flipping it around and forcing the rebase in the opposite direction.  Take the changes from the branch that was reverted and replay them on top of  the revert to produce a new branch that can be merged downstream of the merge and you'll get a slightly cleaner looking history vs the rather hard to follow revert revert.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this post when facing the same problem. I find above wayyy to scary to do reset hards etc.  I'll end up deleting something I don't want to, and won't be able to get it back.

Instead I checked out the commit I wanted the branch to go back to e.g. `git checkout 123466t7632723`. Then converted to a branch `git checkout my-new-branch`.  I then deleted the branch I didn't want any more.  Of course this will only work if you are able to throw away the branch you messed up.

Comment: The `git reflog` will protect you on a hard reset for a couple of months in case you later discover that you need the lost commits. The reflog is limited to your local repo.

Answer (score 1):

If needed you can create a new branch and **cherry-pick** the commits (separate the commit SH with space so it will be one command)  from the reverted pull request, that way you'll be able to merge again with out losing files/changes.