# How do you undo changes committed to main line from a feature branch but keep the branch up to date?

Tags: git

From time to time we can run across issues where we commit a feature branch to our baseline and discover in some situations it can go horribly wrong, so the change needs to be reverted, without losing all the other commits done since then. However, someone needs to continue working on the original branch.

I don't want to use `git rebase` on the main line to change history (because that'd cause all sorts of issues all by itself), but when I do `git revert` on the main line then as soon as `git merge` is run on the branch, to pick up any other changes done to the system, then all the work done disappears.

What can I do to keep the changes on the branch intact?

Comment: Is this a merge commit you're reverting?  If so, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, you're merging the mainline into your branch.  I think the link I provided above will do the trick for you.  You just have to "revert the revert" on your branch.

Comment: ohh. ok, some of the stuff referred to in there looks helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you don't want to do any rebases and resets, this is merge-only approach.

Suppose you have two branches `master` and `feature`.
So, you've decided merge the feature into `master`:

```
$ git merge feature
```

Now, you have all your `feature` changes on the master. I assume the most difficult scenario - there are commits made after the merge on both branches. But, suddenly you see that nothing works of `feature`, all is broken and decide to revert it. Your history is (you could see it with `git log --graph feature master`):

```
* commit 838f29fda2333bdbfc0d1be44d2387e6119dc4e8
| 
|     f3
|    
| * commit 58d1e3f0e032cc77d4ab2bbf0bdfe6407b96b7e6
| | 
| |     m3
| |     
| *   commit afb600fe382befe095f9b8a6e9eef98be25c929b
| |\  Merge: 5cddc52 8660a59
| |/  
|/|   
| |       Merge branch 'feature'
| |   
* | commit 8660a59eeb13f9b3447846ba6977140f7c86c7a4
| | 
| |     f2
| |   
* | commit 6f76e2288d69808b97981340198fd8044ab47630
| | 
| |     f1
| |   
| * commit 5cddc528de424a01d1d18552ddea93435618e2f7
| | 
| |     m2
| |   
| * commit fa6ebb76f9f0308f7dcd1148503534668fa15358
|/  
|   
|       m1
|  
* commit 4e3aa05d6f46eb14bbbc253a42325e9a53a3393e
```

Notice the commits f3 and m3 which have been done after merge. So, you need carefully delete only changes from `feature` appeared in the `master`.

To do it you could revert the merge commit on the `master`, keeping master's base (the parameter `-m1`). To achieve it I create a new branch based on the merge point and revert in it:

```
$ git checkout -b feature-revert afb600fe
$ git revert -m1 HEAD
```

Now, we have a reverted changes on the branch `feature-revert`. Now it is simple just put it into master by merging:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature-revert
```

So, at the moment the `master` doesn't have anything from the `feature`. However, if later you want to re-merge the feature, all reverted changes will be lost in master, as they were merged and reverted.

To solve the issue you should **revert the revert** (he-he) and merge it back to the `feature`:

```
$ git checkout feature-revert
$ git revert HEAD
$ git checkout feature
$ git merge feature-revert
```

I suppose we don't need the branch anymore, as we merged it already, but you could keep it if you want:

```
$ git branch -d feature-revert
```

You should be aware, that merging it back brings all changes from `master` into `feature` which usually normal workflow.

Now, after fixes made in `feature` you could merge it again into `master` as usual anytime.

Answer (score 1):

When you `git revert` your changes, it creates a new commit, whose tree doesn't have those changes.

The changes aren't *removed* though, their original commits still exist.

So, just:

- `git revert` your merge commit on master (remember to select the correct parent). Now master doesn't have the broken code introduced from your feature branch
- fix the feature branch
- revert the first revert on master. This will re-introduce the *broken* state of the feature as you merged it originally
- merge the feature-branch fixes over

See [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) (or the same file in your local git docs if installed) for more details.

You history ends up looking like:

```
 --- a -- ... -- Mi ... ~Mi ... ~~Mi -- Mx  [master]
      \         /                      /
       f1 ... fi -- fj ........ x -- fx     [feature]
```

where `Mi` is your original merge from the feature branch, `~Mi` is the reversion when you noticed the problem, `fj .. fx` are subsequent fixes to the feature branch, `~~Mi` is the reversion of `~Mi`, etc.

Comment: But once I've git reverted the master, I can't merge the master back into the feature branch, which I need to do.

Comment: Yes you can, just _revert the reversion first_. It's the third point in the bullet list above, is denoted `~~Mi` in the graph (and described in the paragraph below), and is shown just under the quote from Linus in the linked document.

Comment: Couldn't one also recreate the branch, as per the linked document, via `git rebase --no-ff a`, where a is the branch point?

Comment: Yes, that works too. It wasn't clear from the question whether new work was still ongoing on the feature branch (`fj..fx`) in addition to the bug fix, and rebasing a branch while people are working on it is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the `git revert` on the feature branch and then merging that back into master?

That way the baselines stay the same and you can continue working on your feature branch.

Comment: How would I keep the changes if I did that? Wouldn't that remove the changes? If I reverted the reversion immediately, would subsequent merges work or would  they delete the changes again?