# Git / Github : Commit got lost

Tags: git, github, git-merge, revert, pull-request

Here is the scenario that happened (I suppose that's how my problem appeared, but not 100% sure) :

- Someone sent a PR, I did merge it but then I reverted it, using the Github `revert` button
- He did another PR with the same Commits (plus one to correct the error)
- I merged it (using Github `merge` button)
- **The commits that has been reverted at the first PR had disappeared from the main repo !**

Why did that happened ? How is it possible that now, from the fork that did the PR, it's saying `There isn't anything to compare` although those commits are not on the branch original of the distant repo..

And finally, how can I restore those commits ?

EDIT : As requested, here is the interesting par of my `git log` :

```
* | |   25f28fb Merge branch 'FooUser-develop' into develop
|\ \ \
| * \ \   73768b7 Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/FooUser/mainRepo into FooUser-develop
| |\ \ \
| | * | | 2e61235 Invert adresses
* | | | |   d522031 Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/mainUser/mainRepo into develop
|\ \ \ \ \
| |/ / / /
|/| | | |
| * | | |   1e6e61b Merge pull request #946 from mainUser/revert-945-develop
| |\ \ \ \
| | * | | | 6767f03 (origin/revert-945-develop) Revert "Corrections"
| |/ / / /
| * | | |   5ccc9cd Merge pull request #945 from FooUser/develop
| |\ \ \ \
| | |/ / /
| | * | | 6e0c08b Corrections structuration
| | * | | f7ade9b Correction
| | * | | 4844437 Nb to Str
| | * | | 1729a83 Fix adress
| | * | | ceab88d Corrections: @ssert
| | * | | a3c8d1a #891 Fix
| |/ / /
```

I apparently lost most of the first commits (`#891 Fix` for example).

Searching a bit more, I found for example that some files I added in `a3c8d1a` ***(first commit)*** were correctly merged on `73768b7` ***(second to last)*** - they weren't just beore, on `d522031`, because of the Revert - but then disappeared at `25f28fb` ***(last one)***.

EDIT 2 :
**I think the problem was because the fork wasn't sync (he didn't git pull / merge when I accepted his PR and then Reverted it). How could I prevent that ?**
(by the way to "fix" it I had to Cherry Pick all the commits missing..)

Comment: Can you provide us a `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` from your repository?

Comment: There are lots of other commits, I gonna try to clean it a bit !

Comment: Just the last 10 commits should be enough to better understand the situation. Just add `-10` to the previous command.

Comment: Just updated my post, hope that's clear enough.

Comment: I think the problem was because the fork wasn't sync (he didn't `git pull` / `merge` when I accepted his PR and then Reverted it). How could I prevent that ? (by the way to "fix" it I had to Cherry Pick all the commits missing..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you revert a merge commit, you need to revert the revert first before you can merge the branch again.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078209/1049112

Which references http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. So when you've got a public repo you really have to be careful about that I guess. Thanks !