# How do you re-merge a reverted merge

Tags: git

In our past life we had a branching system that was .. incorrect.
We had to revert a merge because we decided to not release the feature.

Now we are ready to release the feature and i'm having a hard time figuring out how to get them remerged.

I made a new branch from that previous branch just for tracking purposes and merged in the latest from our main line. But I haven't been able to figure out how to merge it back into the main line.

Comment: This is a dupe of several other questions in the last few days

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to go about doing it.

1. You could use `git revert` on the revert commit for the merge.  Make sure any later changes are not overwritten.
2. Depending on the what files are changed in the feature, you can checkout the files from the original with `git checkout`.  Then you can do a single commit that introduces the feature.  This can be tricky if later changes would be overwritten by the past files.
3. `git cherry-pick` the commits that make the changes for the features.  If there are only a couple of commits that you can easily identify for the feature, this can work.  It will create new commits reintroducing the changes.  Just make sure that you apply the commits in the correct order.

No matter what, you will need to have one or more new commits that reintroduce the change.  It isn't going to be a matter of remerging the branch.

IMO, the easiest option would probably be the first.  Just make sure that you verify everything on your local repo before pushing.  That way you can modify the commit without causing any trouble.

Comment: Hey @Schleis I tried #1 on the hash that was my revert but it's giving me a Mainline is specific but commit was not a merge?

Answer (score 1):

With a clean working tree on that branch, switch back to the main line (master?) and `git merge <branchname>` or you can use rebase to apply all the changes of that other branch on top of the current "main line" (master?)