# Force comparison of two branches

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch called `master` and a branch called `feature`. A week ago I merged `feature` into `master` but then realized the feature wasn't really ready yet, so I `revert`ed the merge.

Now I'm ready to merge `feature` into `master` again, but only some files were merged - because Git is looking at the history and thinks that the master `revert` should take precedence and not include a bunch of files that exist in `feature` that I really do want.

What I want is a way to interactively look at the diff between the two branches and select which files I want to keep, deal with any merge conflicts, etc. But git `merge` refuses to acknowledge any difference between these two branches.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is `revert` in your question? and did you revert using `git reset --hard <merge-commit> -1`

Comment: I used `git revert <commit>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this interesting [Git revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert)

The beauty about this problem is, the best feature ot `git revert` is creating the problem. The biggest advantage of using git revert from git reset is

> It doesn’t change the **project history**, which makes it a “safe”
>   operation for commits that have already been published to a shared
>   repository. For details about why altering shared history is
>   dangerous, please see the git reset page.

`git revert` in itself is a commit. You should have used `git reset --hard`, I am guessing you had a reason for using git revert.

> It's important to understand that git revert undoes a single commit—it
>   does not “revert” back to the previous state of a project by removing
>   all subsequent commits.

To undo a merge before you push commits.

```
git revert -m 1 <commit>
```

But remember the real problem here is, you have to revert the revert before you want to commit the brach again, or re-merge it again.

Anyways, I have found a wonderful person on this planet, who explained in detailed exactly the same problem. Yes, Exactly the same problem. I am excited to present him here:

[Linux Torvalds explaining the git-revert conflict](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

> I have a master branch.  We have a branch off of that that some
>       developers are doing work on.  They claim it is ready. We merge it
>       into the master branch.  It breaks something so we revert the merge.
>       They make changes to the code.  they get it to a point where they say
>       it is ok and we merge again.
>
> When examined, we find that code changes made before the revert are
>   not in the master branch, but code changes after are in the master
>   branch.

This might also help you:

[Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)