# Git revert catastrophe

Tags: git, github

Consider the following situation.

I have two branches: `main` and `main_feature_#1`.

1. I created a pull request and **merged** `main_feature_#1` into `main`.
   I found some issue with the merge and there was no way out — had to **revert** this merge; did this locally and pushed it.
2. Checkout out `main_feature_#1` and reverted one of the commits.

Now when I open a pull request for `main` vs `main_feature_#`, the only commit that is shown is the last revert made on `main_feature_#`. Local merge from `main_feature_#1` into `main` also shows the same thing. `git diff main main_feature_#1` shows all the changes though.

However, a pull request for `main_feature_#1` vs `main` shows all the differences for a proper merge.

I don't know what to do anymore. :(

Comment: Did you revert the revert first?

Comment: You mean I have to revert the revert I made on `main`? And Why?

Comment: Or are you technically saying that I should have never reverted the merge in the first place. Just reverted something in `main_feature_#1` and then opened a new pull request.

Comment: `main_feature_#1` is a terrible name for a git identifier. The `#` character is the comment character in Unix shells, so to use the identifier correctly in Unix command lines, you will always have to be quoting the # character or the entire identifier.

Comment: I never need to do that on the Mac; and this is the convention my workplace follows; sorry about this!

Comment: [Here's a reference to what I'm talking about.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)  It sounds like your scenario is identical (and all of the changes from `main_feature#1` *would* be present on your branch; it just so happens that a later commit came in and reversed their additions.  It's not as if the merge never happened.)

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you please post the same thing in an answer; would like to accept. Thanks again!

Comment: If the duplicate answer helped you out, feel free to close this as a dupe of that.   I wouldn't want to repeat information that's already out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with merge reverts. There are several ways to fix it. The easiest is to use `git cherry-pick` to reapply those commits anew, but can be tedious on a longer branch history. I usually do rebase with all three params `git rebase --onto main_feature_#1 <start of the main_feature_#1> <first commit before the unwanted merge> --interactive`.

Comment: This would make more of a mess of things.

Comment: @Makoto not if branch was simple. Otherwise you can always reset back.

Comment: Please see @Makoto's answer in the comments. It's pretty much close to perfect and it's very clean.