# Committing a reverted commit without reverting the revert?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit

In my git master branch history something like this has happened.

Assume I have progressed up-to a point (A). And I added some commits (say B, C and D) which was merged from another branch.

```
(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)
```

Then I understood that I don't want to add them now for some reason and I reverted those. So now,

```
(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(-D)--(-C)--(-B)
```

Then I have added some other commits. Assume (E), (F), (G).

```
(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(-D)--(-C)--(-B)--(E)--(F)--(G)
```

Now, I suddenly want that commits (B, C, D) to be merged via that older branch. So that finally it looks,

```
(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(-D)--(-C)--(-B)--(E)--(F)--(G)--(B)--(C)--(D)
```

But just because it already has the commits (B, C, D) in history, I can't do that. Can someone please tell me that what is the ideal solution here.??

Please don't ask me to revert the reverts or undo the past that I cannot.

Comment: Can't you just cherry-pick the older commits (B, C, D) back onto the current branch? Or is that not working for you?

Comment: @Ajedi32 though I mentioned them as B, C, D there are very large number of commits (not 3). So It won't work for me anyway. And also It should raise the same problem right? since they are in history?

Comment: What did you try before to restore the commits? Anyway, you reverted each commit before with `git revert`, so why is cherry-picking to get them back particularly burdensome?

Comment: @Ajedi32 actually I reverted the merges, not commits, but I can't cherry-pick merges right? Can I? I just tried merging. :))

Comment: In that case: Possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Comment: @Ajedi32 I also found that.. but it is asking to revert the reverts. ://

Comment: Why can't you revert the reverts? If `H` is the original merge, and `I` is the revert of that merge, is there a reason you can't create commit `J` that is a revert of `I`?

Comment: @ScottWeldon definitely I can do.. But it shows my work as reverts in the history right.. not commits.. I want my work to show in history as commits.. not reverts.. to appear it nice. :)) if there's no solution for that.. I definitely go for reverting the reverts. :))

Comment: Well the original commits (`B`, `C`, and `D`) will still be in the history either way, and AFAIK, the only difference between a revert and a normal commit is Git adds e.g. `Reverts commit aaaabb` to the commit message (and you can edit that). So in the scenario I gave, there shouldn't much difference between commit `J` being (1) a revert of `I` which is a revert of the merge `H`, or (2) a new merge commit from your branch.

Comment: If you'd still like to try a new merge: what was the error you got when you tried to merge? You said you can't do that, but why is that? Also relevant: are you merging with `--ff-only` or `--no-ff`?