# Successful git merge into master is not showing any changes on GitHub or after git pull from master branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I successfully merged a PR into `master`. When I inspect `master` in GitHub, the changes are not shown, yet GitHub says that the merge into `master` was successful.

I am trying to get the content of (at this point) ANY of these branches into master: `new_react_in_nav_bar_branch`, `revert-16-add_react_to_nav_bar`, or `add_react_to_nav_bar` (ideally, the first of these three). I have made a huge mess of things.

[The repo can be found here.](https://github.com/noahmilstein/breakable_toy/branches)

This is the output of `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`:

```
*   e824c42 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #19 from noahmilstein/new_react_in_nav_bar_branch
|\
| * 8626d40 (origin/new_react_in_nav_bar_branch) fixed codeship build failure
| * 1ca3f73 added capybara webkit
* |   9ca1f50 Merge pull request #17 from noahmilstein/revert-16-add_react_to_nav_bar
|\ \
| * | 390c5e1 (origin/revert-16-add_react_to_nav_bar) Revert "Add react to nav bar"
|/ /
* |   81c87d1 Merge pull request #16 from noahmilstein/add_react_to_nav_bar
|\ \
| |/
| | * 8406ea5 (origin/add_react_to_nav_bar) added capybara webkit
| |/
| * a66de71 nav bar is now react
| * df8319c (origin/fix_tagging) WIP, waiting on SOF answer
|/
*   136e6ec Merge pull request #15 from noahmilstein/add_react
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurred because you:

1. Merged `add_react_to_nav_bar` into `master`.
2. Reverted that merge in commit `390c5e1`. In the future, try to avoid reverting a merge, see below.
3. Merged `new_react_in_nav_bar_branch`, which is based on `add_react_to_nav_bar`, into `master`.

As explained in [the Git docs](//www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt), reverting a merge reverts the changes, but it doesn't change the history, so Git still sees that the original merge occurred. Thus, Git ignores any changes from before that merge, because those changes have already been merged once.

To work around this, as explained in [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](//stackoverflow.com/q/1078146/2747593), you have to revert the revert (in this case `390c5e1`. Do:

```
git revert 390c5e1
```

(If you want, you can create a new branch first, and submit that branch as a PR.)

In the future, instead of reverting a merge, if possible, try to find the specific commit that is faulty (`git bisect` can be helpful here) and revert that. If you have no choice but to revert the merge, then you can use the above solution.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get that to work. I resolved this issue but it was rather ugly workaround.

Comment: @n.milsht What happened when you tried my solution? How did you resolve your issue? For the latter, feel free to [self-answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly solve this so much as work around it in a rather sloppy fashion. The changes I wanted to commit weren't extensive so I branched off of master and just copied the changes I wanted to commit into this new branch. Not exactly a solution but I couldn't waste anymore time on the problem.