# A revert merge is breaking breaking history

Tags: git, merge

10 days ago I accidentally merge a feature branch (feature/calendar) into develop branch. After that I revert it.

In between, the were some commits made on both branches.

Now, I want to merge feature/calendar into develop. The issue is that the changes made by the revert (10 days ago) are posterior to the current work, so when I make a diff between the 2 branches the work previously reverted is missing.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly - can you not just rebase your feature branch and then merge into develop? `git fetch origin/develop && git rebase origin/develop`

Comment: @jody_lognoul Can you attach a demo example of what you want actually?

Comment: Yes it's the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git thank you btw :-)