# How to fix messed up (and pushed) merge without push --force

Tags: git

I was asked by my colleague to assist with following issue:

- He was working in a branch `feature`
- He merged `master` into `feature`, which resulted in a huge swath of conflicts
- He resolved many of the conflicts by "take theirs" or "take mine", often incorrectly.
- He commited and pushed the merge.
- He realized what he has done and called for help.

My first instinct was to move the pointer back using `branch -f`, but that requires `push --force`, which is disabled on the repo.

Second attempt was `git revert -m`, which however reverted the merge completely and blocked me from doing again, saying "Already up-to date" (since technically all those commits from `master` *were* aready merged in `feature`).

As an immediate solution, I ended up discarding the branch and making a new, fixed one.

Is there a better way to fix this situation that doesn't require `push --force`?

Comment: Could you clarify "blocked me from doing again"?  Blocked you from doing what again?  I do believe reverting is the correct approach here so I would continue along that path.

Comment: If he is the only person who works with the branch `feature` than it is better to `reset` and `push -f`. If not I agree with @jbu.

Comment: @jbu When you attempt to merge after such revert, you get "Already up-to date", because at that point, `master`'s current tip (and all commits leading to it) is already merged into `feature`. It's just that `feature` has locally chosen to discard those changes.

Comment: Another thought is to just soft reset feature back prior to the original commit and then add, commit and push.  But regarding the already up to date message, a revert will add a commit so there is absolutely no way the remote would have that unless i am misunderstanding something fundamental about git.

Comment: "reverted the merge completely and blocked me from doing again" this is known issue, and there are some ideas how to handle it https://stackoverflow.com/q/1078146/2303202 just for example, actually there are a lot of very similar questions. Since non of the fix ideas are ideal forced push is not that bad solution if you can afford it (that is: all your developers are able to rebase after you forcepush)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
$ git reset --hard @commit
```

If the merge was the last commit you can replace `@commit` by `HEAD^` otherwise replace by the last commit before the merge one.

This will get you back how you were before the problematic merge.