# Apply changes that have been merged and then reverted

Tags: git, merge

The problem is: we want to merge `topic` into `master`, but `topic` is an ancestor of `master`, so the merge is a no-op. A commit between `topic` and `master` had reverted the previous merge of `topic` into `master`. It did that using `reset` not `revert`. Now, a `diff` between `master..topic` shows all the changes that we want to apply. How do we apply those changes?

```
       C      B      A      D
master * ---- * ---- * ---- * ---- * 
                       \ 
                        \
                   topic * ---- * ---- * ---- *
```

- `A` was a `merge`.
- `B` reverted both `A` and `D` but without using `revert`.
- `C` added additional commits

Edit:

`B` reverted more than `A`, but we want to re-apply only the changes that `A` introduced. Therefore, reverting `B` will not accomplish our goal, because it will restore `D`.

Comment: Just `git revert B`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Unfortunately, I failed to mention that `B` backed out more than the merge of `topic`. Apologies.

Comment: Hmm, so that means the `master..topic` diff you mentioned is actually a *superset* of the changes you wish to make?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No. `master..topic` is the exact set of changes we wish to make.

Comment: hmm, which version of reset did you use?

Comment: @JeffWang We did a `reset --hard D~1`, then a `reset --soft A`, and finally a `commit -m "Reverted a few commits"`.

Comment: Are there commits between A, B and C?  I'm assuming there were some commits between D and A?

Comment: @JeffWang This is a simplified diagram and there were other commits between A, B, C, and D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some options:

1. You can revert B and revert D.
   Reverting B will restore D, so you revert D again.
2. If the diff is showing just what you want to apply, you can create a patch file from the diff and apply that patch file in the master branch.

Create the patch:

```
git diff master..topic > file.patch
```

Go to master and apply the patch:

```
git apply file.patch
```

Comment: Creating and applying a patch fit the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

[Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Short answer: revert the revert.  but there are gotchas you should look at in the git documentation

Comment: yes, use git log to find the ref that you did the reset, revert that ref, and it's the same thing.

Comment: My apologies. I've updated my answer because I left out an important detail.