# git revert will not let me re commit changes I reverted from

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, pull-request

So I made a Pull Request in bitbucket, then I merged that in. I did a deploy and I had an unexpected mirgration failure that wasn't present on my local environment. So from there I hit the

```
Revert
```

button on the merged PR. This created a new PR that removed all the old code including the migration from the first PR. So then I merged that one in. Now I fixed the migration, but I can't create a PR because it says the code already lives in the master branch. How do I re create that first pull request now?

Comment: Hi use git reflog to show you a list of commits HEAD pointed to the version you want git checkout -b after-commit HEAD@{1} //adapt to your context, regard.

Comment: Are you using GitHub, or Bitbucket? They are not the same thing. Both give you a web interface atop Git, but they use different web interfaces. Don't use both tags!

Comment: Hit revert button on the PR that reverted the original changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Comment: @1615903 if you make that comment an answer then I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Hit revert button on the PR that reverted the original changes. This will create a new PR once again, reverting the first revert.