# git revert and pull from one branch to another

Tags: git, git-merge, pull, revert

- Have 2 branches (say A & B) merged the changes from A to B (executed
  git pull . A in branch B). There was a merge commit that happened.
- Now had to revert that merge on B (so did git revert -m)
- So due to revert, the commits from A are reverted back in B
- There are other commits on B done later on

Now when I again try to pull from A to B, those changes that were reverted are not being pulled. How do I pull those changes as well?

Comment: Can you show us the exact `git revert` command you ran?

Comment: If you reverted the commits, those stay reverted. If you want to remove the revert, you could delete the revert commit or revert it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to merge A again, it fails because those commits are already on B although a later revert commit has undone their changes.

Now if you want to merge them again, just revert that revert commit. It brings back the reverted changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

The last three commits (HEAD, HEAD^, and HEAD~2) were bad and you do not want to ever see them again. Do not do this if you have already given these commits to somebody else.