# Git unable to create new pull request after merge reverted

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request, git-revert

Updated:

I have merged my branch "A" into the develop branch "B", but found some code not really there yet so reverted it in the branch "B".

Now I update the code in "A"  and try to create a new pull request for merging "A" to "B" again. I just found that I am unable to create the new pull request with the earlier changes (the bits that have been reverted). Any suggestion?

Besides, there are some new commit into the "B" after the revert.

Comment: Can you pleas specify better branch structure and list of actions you performed?

Comment: Your question needs more information. What did you do _specifically_? Please don't comment, but instead edit the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git)

Comment: I am not just merging back directly, but need to create a pull request, which is just not working as mentioned in the ticket.