# Git merge in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual studio 2022 for Git.

I have a '`master`' branch and, from `master` branch, I created another '`feature`' branch.
Then I added 2 commits in `feature` branch

- Question 1: When I merge the 2 commits to '`master`' branch, then in history I can see only one merge commit in '`master`' branch.
  When merging, why 2 commits are not showing, but only a merge commit?
- Question 2: I added a commit in `feature` branch and then merged to '`master`' branch.
  Then later, I reverted this commit in '`master`' branch for temporarily taking a build.
  Now when I try to merge the `feature` branch to `master` branch for this commit to add to `master` branch because of merging before, now no commits are showing to merge.
  What would be the best practice to merge the commits again ?

Answer (score 2):

> when merging why 2 commits are not showing, but only a merge commit?

Because that is what a merge produces: a merge commit, which group the commits from the merged branch to one single commit.

> what would be the best practice to merge the commits again ?

You could, on master, [revert the revert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078209/6309): that way, you can keep merging the feature branch without having to worry about the past commit (which was reverted on master).

---

> for each commits, I use to add comments so that I can track, but when merging branch, I cannot track this, so is there any way I can avoid this?

2 options:

- either you can display the log of the merged branch from a merged commit:

  ```
  git log <sha>^2
  ```

(replace `<sha>` with the reference to a merge commit whose merge history you want to track)

- or [*rebase*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) your merged branch on top of target, especially if you are the only one working on `feature` branch.

  ```
  git switch master
  git rebase feature
  ```

There the history will be linear.

Comment: for each commits, I use to add comments so that I can track, but when merging branch, I cannot track this, so is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: @JijuJohn I have edited the answer to address your comment.